# How to avoid duplicate code when validating multiple input fields?

Tags: java, javafx, code-duplication

How to avoid duplicate code when validating multiple input fields like `TextField`s, `DatePicker`s, `ChoiceBox`es? This code below belongs to the service class which is used by `StageAddController` to listen and validates input. When the focus is lost and field is empty field border gets red.

```
public void validateForEmptyTextField(TextField textField, PseudoClass errorClass){
    textField.focusedProperty().addListener((arg0, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (!newValue) { //when focus lost
            if(textField.getText().trim().isEmpty()){
                textField.pseudoClassStateChanged(errorClass, true);
            }
            else
                textField.pseudoClassStateChanged(errorClass, false);
        }
    });
}

public void validateForEmptyDatePicker (DatePicker datePicker, PseudoClass errorClass){
    datePicker.focusedProperty().addListener((arg0, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (!newValue) { //when focus lost
            if(datePicker.getValue() == null){
                datePicker.pseudoClassStateChanged(errorClass, true);
            }
            else
                datePicker.pseudoClassStateChanged(errorClass, false);
        }
    });
}

public void validateForEmptyChoiceBox (ChoiceBox<String > stringChoiceBox, PseudoClass errorClass){
    stringChoiceBox.focusedProperty().addListener((arg0, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (!newValue) { //when focus lost
            if(stringChoiceBox.getValue() == null){
                stringChoiceBox.pseudoClassStateChanged(errorClass, true);
            }
            else
                stringChoiceBox.pseudoClassStateChanged(errorClass, false);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved by introducing a generic parameter `T` which extends `Node` (1) and passing a `Predicate<T>` (2):

```
public <T extends Node> void validateNodeForEmptyByPredicate(
    T node,
    PseudoClass errorClass,
    Predicate<T> predicate
) {
    node.focusedProperty().addListener((arg0, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (!newValue) {
            node.pseudoClassStateChanged(errorClass, predicate.test(node)); // *
        }
    });
}
```

- (1) it is needed to have access to the `focusedProperty` method;
- (2) it is gonna decide if a `T` is empty, for instance:

  - for `TextField`s -> `field -> field.getText().trim().isEmpty()`;
  - for `DatePicker`s -> `picker -> picker -> picker.getValue() == null`;
  - for `ChoiceBox`es -> `box -> box.getValue() == null`.

I would like to rewrite the following code block (*)

```
if (predicate.test(node)) {
    node.pseudoClassStateChanged(errorClass, true);
} else {  
    node.pseudoClassStateChanged(errorClass, false);
}
```

into:

```
node.pseudoClassStateChanged(errorClass, predicate.test(node));
```